# Check whether query compiles on particular database

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I can have different queries, before running them I want to know whether those queries can be compiled on the target database.

Here is an example; I don't want to use `TRY` and `CATCH` block since I might have `INSERT`, `UPDATE` or below script might be within stored procedure. All I want to do is if it doesn't compile - skip

```
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX) = '';            
DECLARE @Query VARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @DBName VARCHAR(100),@ID INT,@Cnt INT;

SET @Query = 'SELECT a.Field1,b.Field2 FROM {DB}.dbo.Table1 a INNER JOIN {DB}.dbo.Table2 b ON a.ID=b.ID ';

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #TemplateDbs;

CREATE TABLE #TemplateDbs
(
    ID        INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    DBName    VARCHAR(100),
    Processed BIT DEFAULT 0
);  
     
INSERT INTO #TemplateDbs(DBName)
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        '[' + name + ']'
    FROM    
        [master].[sys].Databases;

SELECT @ID = MIN(ID) FROM #TemplateDbs WHERE Processed = 0;

WHILE(@ID IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
    SELECT @DBName = DBName FROM #TemplateDbs WHERE ID = @ID;
    SET @SQL = @Query;
    SET @SQL = REPLACE(@SQL,'{DB}',@DBName);

    EXEC (@SQL);

    UPDATE #TemplateDbs 
    SET Processed = 1 
    WHERE ID = @ID;

    SELECT @ID = MIN(ID) FROM #TemplateDbs WHERE Processed = 0;
END
```

Comment: you cold probably use [sys-dm-exec-describe-first-result-set](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-describe-first-result-set-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: `SET @SQL = REPLACE(@SQL,'{DB}',@DBName);` -> I would rather do dynamic SQL against multiple databases using `DECLARE @exec nvarchar(max) = QUOTENAME(@DBName) + N'.sys.sp_executesql'; EXEC @exec @SQL;` -> then then `@SQL` doesn't have to be littered with non-parseable `{DB}` stuff.

Comment: Can you not just add `SET PARSEONLY ON` at the start of the script? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-parseonly-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: Sounds like a bad idea, also, what has TRY/CATCH to do with procedures etc. Why not just check for OBJECT_ID('{db}..yourtable') and only run queries where the objects you want to work with exist

Comment: @siggemannen I imagine if you have a bunch of queries already stored somewhere, parsing them out to know that all the individual object IDs exist (and aren't views or functions that reference other objects not explicitly mentioned in the query that themselves may or may not exist) could be quite a lot more cumbersome.

Comment: @AaronBertrand, yeah i guess, but still, sounds weird to run a bunch of random various queries in random databases. But anyways, `dm_exec_describe_first_result_set` is a pretty neat trick, although it seems to have same allergies to temp tables as SET FMTONLY

Comment: @siggemannen , as I have mentioned, i have lots of different queries to run, and they are stored in a table. It is hard to parse particular table name out of whole query, might not be possible at all

Comment: @siggemannen I wish it were that weird but I recently built [a whole system around it](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/databases/sql-server/t-sql-programming-sql-server/working-around-schema-drift-sql-server/). And yeah, it has to be the only statement and #temp tables won't work.

Comment: @siggemannen Interestingly, it's not just the presence of #tmp in the query that breaks things, it works fine when a #tmp is referenced and it's not part of the metadata ([example](https://dbfiddle.uk/cUtuE01B)).

Comment: @EricKlaus i don't see why try catch wouldn't work for you

Comment: @AaronBertrand, i'm guessing it runs the query through some other context, where it can no longer find the temporary table by name. Because global temporary tables work fine, so it doesn't seem to be a parser related issue

Comment: @siggemannen Yes, I know, I was just commenting on your "same allergies" comment. People often infer from the error message that the query you pass to the function _can't mention #temp tables at all_.

Comment: @siggemannen , try catch won't work for me since imagine i'm building a view with union on all dbs there, and that script runs within stored procedure, that means that every single time query is valid it will pop out unnecessary results in a results grid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the query is always *a single statement*, we can use `sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set` to tell us if that query parses correctly. Yes, it works for inserts / updates / deletes, not just selects.

And we don't have to litter the query with `{DB}` because we can use the capability of `EXECUTE` to execute any stored procedure, including one passed in as a variable.

We don't need temp tables or identity columns or while loops - a simple local cursor should do.

```
DECLARE @Query  nvarchar(max), -- always nvarchar!
        @Check  nvarchar(max),
        @DBName sysname,
        @exec   nvarchar(1000),
        @cursor cursor,
        @err    tinyint;

SELECT @Query = N'SELECT t1.Field1, t2.Field2 
    FROM dbo.Table1 AS t1 
    INNER JOIN dbo.Table2 AS t2 
    ON t1.ID = t2.ID;',
  @Check = N'SELECT @err = error_state 
    FROM sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set
    (@query, NULL, 0);';

SET @cursor = CURSOR FORWARD_ONLY STATIC READ_ONLY FOR 
  SELECT QUOTENAME(name) FROM sys.databases     
    WHERE database_id > 4 AND state = 0;

OPEN @cursor;
FETCH NEXT FROM @cursor INTO @DBName;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS <> -1
BEGIN
  SET @exec = CONCAT(@DBName, N'.sys.sp_executesql');
  SET @err  = null;
  
  EXEC @exec @Check, 
             N'@err tinyint OUTPUT, @query nvarchar(max)', 
             @err OUTPUT, @query;

  IF @err IS NULL
    EXEC @exec @Query;
END
```

If you have queries already stored somewhere you should simply remove the `{DB}` tokens from the source. Or change the above to say:

```
SET @Query = REPLACE(@Query, N'{DB}.', N'');
```

Comment: This is so elegant, thanks a lot. I was doing Try and catch with dynamic sql, and actually had to query any query to make sure it parses right on each db. Execution time went from 1 hour to 48 seconds